# Inputting data from a file into a data structure

Tags: c, file, data-structures

I am fairly new to programming in C and what I want to do is input data from a file into a data structure. I realise I have some errors in it and I can't figure them out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The text file I am reading from contains this:

```
0001:0002:0003:0021:CLS  
0001:0010:0003:0021:CLS  
0001:0002:0002:0080:<HTML>  
0005:0002:0002:8080:<BR>  
0005:0012:0002:8080:<BR>
```

My code is:

```
int main() {  
banner(); //call on banner  
int exists(const char *filename);  
const char s[2] = ":";  
char filename[500];  
FILE * inputFile;  
FILE * outputFile;  
char *token;  
int n;  
struct Packet;  
Packet *P;  


printf("Input the file name: ");  
    scanf("%s",filename);  
    printf("\n");



    inputFile = fopen(filename, "r");    
    if (inputFile != NULL)    
    {  
        printf("This file exists");      
    }  
    else   
    {  
        printf("This file doesn't exist\n");    


while(P >=sizeof(Packet)){    
           P=(struct Packet*)calloc( 5, sizeof(Packet *) );  
            fscanf(inputFile,"%s %d %d %d", &P->S, &P->D, &P->T, &P->P, &P->D );  
            fprintf(inputFile,"%s %d %d %d %d\n", P->S, P->D, P->T, P->P, P->D);  
        }  


  while(!feof(inputFile)){
        {
            P=(Packet*)calloc( 5, sizeof(struct Packet *) );
            fscanf(inputFile,"%s %d %d %d", P->S, P->D, P->T, P->P, P->D );
            fprintf(inputFile,"%d %d %d %d %s\n", P->S, P->D, P->T, P->P, P->D);
        }
    }
```

Comment: And the errors are...? We can execute some code in our heads, but we're not going to run your program for you...

Comment: hi sorry, the errors are warnings are they relevant or do you want me to post those?

Comment: Of coure they're relevant.

Comment: comparison between pointer and integer, assignment from incompatible pointer type, format %s expects argument of type char but argument 3 has type int, too many arguments for format these are the main warnings seperated by commas

Comment: P is uninitialized and you are using it incorrectly in the while loop.  You are comparing the address the pointer is pointing to to the size of the Packet structure (8060 bytes if packed).  Next, you are allocating five pointer sizes of memory (40 bytes if 64-bit pointers) which is not the same thing as allocating 5 Packets sizes.  Before you try to allocate space and put it in P, try to see if you can read the content and write it to console first because I think your fscanf is also erroneous (if your file is : delimited).

Comment: Do not vandalise your questions once someone has given their time to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest challenge you face is choosing the correct tool for the job. You must also match your struct declaration a bit better to the data you have.

While `scanf` is a good tool, when you have varying lines of input to read, it is not the proper tool for the job. In your data you have `blank lines` and a `varying number of fields` per-line to read. Instead of trying to **shoehorn** a sequence of tests and format string so `scanf` can work, the correct approach is the read an entire line of data from the file and then parse that data to get the needed information.

The proper tools for **line-oriented** input are `fgets` and `getline`. In this instance, I prefer `getline` because it returns the actual number of characters it reads in each line allowing a simple test for empty/short lines.

Once you have read a line of data, the proper tools for the job are either `strtok` or `strsep`. You can also manually parse the line of data with a simple pointer. Regardless, you parse the data and assign the separated values to your structure.

I have left parts of your code commented out below so you can follow the changes. Some simply stylistic, the rest implementing what I describe above. Note, there are many ways to do this. Look it over and let me know if you have questions. Specifically understand why you **do not** need to declare arrays inside your struct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXS 500

// typedef struct __Packet {
//     int Source[500];
//     int Destination[500];
//     int Type[500];
//     int Port[500];
//     char Data[60];
// } Packet;

typedef struct {    /* don't use initial 'C'aps - c isn't c++ or visual basic */
    int src;        /* obviously, you are free to do so, but it's ugly...     */
    int dest;
    int type;
    int port;
    char *data;
} packet;

int main () {

    // banner ();           //call on banner
    // int exists (const char *filename);
    // const char s[2] = ":";
    // char filename[500];
    // char *token;
    // int n;
    // struct Packet;
    // Packet *P;

    char *filename = NULL;
    FILE *iFile = NULL;
    // FILE *oFile = NULL;
    char *line = NULL;      /* NULL forces getline to allocate  */
    size_t n = 0;           /* max chars to read (0 - no limit  */
    ssize_t nchr = 0;       /* number of chars actually read    */
    size_t idx = 0;         /* packet array index               */
    char *p = NULL;         /* general pointer to parse line    */
    char *sp = NULL;        /* pointer to save start address    */
    int i = 0;              /* general iterator                 */

    /* allocate an array of pointers to struct */
    packet **pkt = calloc (MAXS, sizeof (*pkt));
    if (!pkt) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: allocation failed (**pkt)\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf ("\n Input the file name: ");
    scanf ("%m[^\n]%*c", &filename);        /* older scanf versions use 'a' instead of 'm' */
    printf ("\n");

    iFile = fopen (filename, "r");
    if (!iFile) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: unable to open file '%s'\n", filename);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* read each line in iFile  */
    while ((nchr = getline (&line, &n, iFile)) != -1)
    {
        if (nchr < 4)               /* if blank or short line, skip     */
            continue;

        if (line[nchr-1] == '\n')   /* strip newline from end           */
            line[--nchr] = 0;   

        sp = line;                  /* save start address for getline   */

        pkt[idx] = calloc (1, sizeof (**pkt));  /* allocate structure   */
        if (!pkt[idx]) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: allocation failed (pkt[%zd])\n", idx);
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /* parse line and fill struct */
        if ((pkt[idx]->src = atoi (strtok (line, ":"))))
        {
            pkt[idx]->dest = atoi (strtok (NULL, ":"));
            pkt[idx]->type = atoi (strtok (NULL, ":"));
            pkt[idx]->port = atoi (strtok (NULL, ":"));
            if ((p = strtok (NULL, ":")))
                pkt[idx]->data = strdup (p);
        }

        idx++;                      /* increment pkt array index        */
        line = sp;                  /* restore start address of line    */
    }

    if (line) free (line);          /* free buffer allocated by getline */
    if (iFile) fclose (iFile);      /* close file stream when done      */
    if (filename) free (filename);  /* free memory allocate by scanf    */

    /* print array (you can also use 'for (i=0; i<idx; i++)' to iterate)*/
    printf (" array of struct content:\n\n");
    while (pkt[i])
    {
        printf (" pkt[%d]    src: %4d    dest: %4d    type: %4d    port: %4d    data: %s\n",
                i, pkt[i]->src, pkt[i]->dest, pkt[i]->type, pkt[i]->port, pkt[i]->data);
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;                          /* reset iterator variable to zero  */
    while (pkt[i])                  /* free all memory allocated        */
    {
        if (pkt[i]->data) free (pkt[i]->data);
        free (pkt[i]);
        i++;
    }
    if (pkt) free (pkt);

    printf ("\n");                  /* make it pretty   */

    return 0;
}
```

**input:**

```
$ cat dat/structrd.txt
0001:0002:0003:0021:CLS
0001:0010:0003:0021:CLS
0001:0002:0002:0080:
0005:0002:0002:8080:

0005:0012:0002:8080:
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/struct_rd_txt

 Input the file name: dat/structrd.txt

 array of struct content:

 pkt[0]    src:    1    dest:    2    type:    3    port:   21    data: CLS
 pkt[1]    src:    1    dest:   10    type:    3    port:   21    data: CLS
 pkt[2]    src:    1    dest:    2    type:    2    port:   80    data: (null)
 pkt[3]    src:    5    dest:    2    type:    2    port: 8080    data: (null)
 pkt[4]    src:    5    dest:   12    type:    2    port: 8080    data: (null)
```

**Note:** you need to save the starting address of the buffer allocated by `getline` when you use functions (like `strtok`) that clobber the original buffer so that `getline` can accurately keep track of the memory it is using. (bad things happen if you don't `:)`

---

**Version Using `fgets`**

If for some strange read you do not have `getline` available, use `fgets`. That is another proper tool. Then slow down and read the `man page` to see how it is used. Then you can update the program properly. That would include the following changes:

```
// size_t n = 0;           /* max chars to read (0 - no limit  */
...
line = calloc (MAXS, sizeof (char));
if (!line) {
    fprintf (stderr, "error: allocation of line failed.\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* read each line in iFile  */
// while ((nchr = getline (&line, &n, iFile)) != -1)
while ((fgets (line, MAXS, iFile)) != NULL)
{
    nchr = strlen (line);
```

Comment: hi, thank you very much for your very helpful and detailed answer, you have been alot of help and i will sit and attempt to make this work tomorrow haha. Thanks again for your efforts they are greatly appreciated

Comment: Glad I could help. Take your time going through the code. The **#1 mistake** new C programmers make is think they can **skim** the reference manual or a tutorial and start writing code. C is an exact language. That is one of its great strengths. But to really use it, you have to understand what each part of each line does. If you don't understand part of a line, check the `man page` or the c reference manual. Take it slow and give yourself time to digest the details and you will do fine. Last tip. Always compile with **warnings enabled** `-Wall -Wextra` that will point out errors to fix.

Comment: hi i am getting a compiler error on /* read each line in iFile  */
    while ((nchr = getline (&line, &n, iFile)) != -1) its saying that there is an undefined reference to 'getline' from research on the internet apparently it has something to do with the compiler?

Comment: Huh? What compiler are you using? `getline` standardized in POSIX.1-2008. Are you using some weird non-standards compliant compiler? No worries, just use fgets. I'll drop an update.

Comment: Take a look at the changes at the end under **Version using fgets**.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the errors I've found are:

- `while(P >=sizeof(Packet))` This check seems to be completely meaningless. Please look at the `EOF` constant to determine when to end the loop.
- `(struct Packet*)` Don't use the keyword `struct` here, as `Packet` already is a typedef for a struct.
- `calloc(5, sizeof(Packet *))`  You don't want to allocate the size of a pointer, but the size of the actual struct.
- `&P->Source, &P->Destination, ...` You don't have to pass the address of the array (`&`), since an array itself **is** a pointer.
- `fprintf(inputFile,"%s %d %d %d %d\n"` The `%s` specifier should be the last one, since the first one's are int arrays. Also you have to dereference the `int` arrays to print a number.

I think you should look into arrays and pointers at more detail.

Comment: hi thank you for your help, i have applied the changes you mentioned